# Spring Security - ошибка создания бина roleDaoImp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

У меня имеется полностью рабочее CRUD прилодение на базе Spring MVC + Hibrnate, я пытаюсь интегрировать в него spring Security, но натыкаюсь на ошибки. Пробовал несколько разных способов, но все-равно никак.

Ошибка 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleDaoImp' defined in file [C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\Spring-Security\target\Spring-Security\WEB-INF\classes\com\spring\dao\RoleDaoImp.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Класс с конфигурацией гибернейта, класс с инициализацией приложения и LoginSuccessHandler пропущу, ибо там все и так хорошо. И сервисы, и классы с кодом, касающиеся сущности User, так же пропущу.

Проблема с сущностью ролей, поэтому ниже представляю код.
Если будет проще, то ссылка на [гитхаб](https://github.com/relizerel/Spring-Security)

Итак, конфиги приложения
WebConfig.java

```java
package com.spring.config;
//куча импортов
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.spring")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public WebConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }


    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }


    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

SpringSecurityInitializer.java

```java
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```java
//куча импортов
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("ADMIN").password("ADMIN").roles("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .withUser("USER").password("USER").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("EDITOR").password("EDITOR").roles("EDITOR");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin()
                // указываем страницу с формой логина
                .loginPage("/login")
                //указываем логику обработки при логине
                .successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler())
                // указываем action с формы логина
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                // Указываем параметры логина и пароля с формы логина
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                // даем доступ к форме логина всем
                .permitAll();

        http
                .logout()
                // разрешаем делать логаут всем
                .permitAll()
                // указываем URL логаута
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                // указываем URL при удачном логауте
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index?logout")
                //выклчаем кроссдоменную секьюрность (на этапе обучения неважна)
                .and().csrf().disable();

        http
                // делаем страницу регистрации недоступной для авторизированных пользователей
                .authorizeRequests()
                //страницы аутентификаци доступна всем
                .antMatchers("/login", "/").anonymous()
                // защищенные URL
                .antMatchers("/users/**").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_EDITOR')")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_EDITOR')")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/editor/**").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_EDITOR', 'ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Класс с конфигурацией гибернейта, класс с инициализацией приложения и LoginSuccessHandler пропущу, ибо там все и так хорошо.

Код, касающийся сущности User так же пропущу, там вроде тоже все хорошо.

Проблема с сущностью ролей, поэтому ниже представляю код.

Role.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String role;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    )
    private List<User> userRoles;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public List<User> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(List<User> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

}
```

RoleDao.java

```java
public interface RoleDao {
    Role getRole(int id);
}
```

RoleDaoImp.java

```java
@Component
@Repository
public class RoleDaoImp implements RoleDao {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public RoleDaoImp(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public Role getRole(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(Role.class, id);
    }
}
```

CustomUserDetailsService.java

```java
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    public User loadUserByUsername(String login)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        com.spring.model.User domainUser = userDao.getUserByLogin(login);

        return new User(
                domainUser.getLogin(),
                domainUser.getPassword(),
                true,
                true,
                true,
                true,
                getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getId())
        );
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
        return getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
    }

    public List<String> getRoles(Integer role) {

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (role == 1) {
            roles.add("ROLE_EDITOR");
            roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");
        } else if (role == 2) {
            roles.add("ROLE_EDITOR");
        }
        return roles;
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А ларчик просто открывался...
Ответ на вопрос - забыл поставить @PersistenceContext в RoleDaoImp и вместо него инициализировал конструктор, на что идея никак не отреагировала...

Вопрос решен, в принципе.

Но если есть что добавить по коду - буду рад.